# How to get auto fill values(default values) on serializer create method in django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model like this:

```
class Post(BaseModel):
        post_user_id = models.CharField(max_length=500, unique=True, default=create_uid)
```

create_uid gerenrates a unique id

serializer:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print(validated_data['post_user_id'])
        return super().create(validated_data)
```

For each created post a post_user_id will be generated automatically and the user will not post the post_user_id
On `print(validated_data['post_user_id'])` I want to print the generate number
But I get error

```
KeyError
```

Comment: can you show printing the full  validated_data? i don't think you pass anything related to post_user_id to the api

Comment: As I said post_user_id is auto-generated and the user won't post it manually

Comment: yes but where are you using this create_uid() function? that the key part you missing from your question, also you do realize that having `fields = '__all__'` in your serializer make that the  input post_user_id is also available on the API request body right?

Comment: On models I'm using: `default=create_uid` so the user won't enter the `post_user_id` and default value comes from create_uid

Comment: yes, but that only trigger when you create the model without passing Post value into it. In your create function `print(validated_data['post_user_id'])` will print out the API input `BEFORE` you create the Post object, so that why it return KeyError because you didn't pass any post_user_id in your API in the first place

Comment: So what if I want the values `after` creation?

Comment: you have it after the you call create(). `post_obj = super().create(validated_data)  print(post_obj.post_user_id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default values gets assigned when the instance is created. You are trying to print before that. If you want to get the id in craete function ,you can print after calling the super.create() .  Do not forget to return the object later.

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    obj=  super().create(validated_data)
    print(obj.post_user_id)
    return obj
```